# Multiple documents update in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

**What is the best way to update multiple documents in couchbase in one go?**

Means I have to update similar kind of information in multiple couchbase documents. The simple way is fetching all these documents in java and then updating them, which is not a good solution.

Does couchbase provide some kind of functionality or API, which can be used? Given that, the document structure of all these documents is the same.

We have searched the couchbase website but nothing is available.

Thanks.

Comment: "fetching all these documents in java and then updating them" why is this not a good solution for you?

Comment: Have you take a look at N1QL? I find it hard to believe you wouldn't find anything about that on the Couchbase website...

Comment: The 3 main ways are:
1. Get the docs and replace them.  For updating small numbers of docs (a few thousand) where you have the keys this is a perfectly fine solution.  You can use the Java reactive API to parallelise the operations easily.
2. Use the Sub-Document API.  This is an optimization of (1) in that the doc does not need to be fetched first.
3. Use N1QL.  Perfect if you don't have the keys or need to update a large number of docs.

Answer (score 1):

When We want to update multiple document in couchbase it's possible but when something happened in between the transaction (any exception) then couchbase not supporting rollback mechanism.

For this you have to use :
[Couchbase Transactions](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/learn/data/transactions.html)

For Spring boot developers:
[Spring Boot data with Couchbase Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.transactions)

Answer (score 0):

[@Az.Mayo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030340/az-mayo) is right - but note that N1QL doesn't support transactions - you will need the Java SDK specifically for the [Couchbase Transactions](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/learn/data/transactions.html).

- Couchbase docs for update: [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030340/az-mayo)